# How the "heroes" gets accessed in Angular2 tutorial

Tags: angular

All:

I am pretty new to Angular2(3 days study), after finishing the tutorial, one thing I am kinda wondering is:

**How do I remember which Component/Service/Module from which file(Module)?**

Do I have to force to remember them, or when I need a feature, there is a way to figure out where it is on Angular site?

If I have to remember some of most-important(commonly used), which Module/Service/Component should on the top list?

Thanks

Comment: Just structure your app correctly. https://angular.io/styleguide

Comment: You can find all the angular modules in the api documentation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#

Comment: @d3l33t Thanks, very helpful.  I wonder how do I know which module I need to use, for example: `BrowserModule`, how do I know I should import this if I do not understand what is needed from it?